# Xaml binding to object StorageFile is not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, storagefile

I got strange behavior where binding to StorageFile itself does not work.

Code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MatchDataConverter}, ConverterParameter=SportName, FallbackValue=DisplayName}" >
```

Binding to this textblock is StorageFile from my local storage of WP8.1.
If I set the value to DisplayName or some property from the StorageFile itself, it works fine. However if I want to send the entire StorageFile to converter ( which I do ) that does not work, displaying fallback value right away.

Can someone point out the problem here ? Thanks

Comment: Could you post your `MatchDataConverter` ?

Comment: it is not getting inside the converter at all. even if I put just 'return value;' inside Convert method, it does not go there, so it does not seem like it is an issue with converter

Comment: What is the `SportName` that used as the `ConverterParameter`? remove the `ConverterParameter` from the binding expression, see if the Convert method is hit.

Comment: it does not work, i removed everything except {Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MatchDataConverter}} and still not working. When I change Path=. to Path=DisplayName ( property of StorageFile ) it works. I cannot figure it out